# Looking for a way to change a boolean to a boolean array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I am trying to get this method to return an array of boolean values. The boolean values will be true or false depending on whether the given floor integer is higher or equal (true) to the values in someNumbers[i] or lower (false).

For example if the floor value is 19 and someNumbers contains: 1, 785, 17, 56, 78. The boolean array would be false, true, false, true, true.

Here is my Java method:

```
public boolean[] boolsRule(int floor, int[] someNumbers) {

    boolean[] results;
    for (int i = 0; i < someNumbers.length; i++) {
        results = (someNumbers[i] >= floor) ? true : false;
    }

    return results;
}
```

Here is the error message I get:

`error: incompatible types
results = (someNumbers[i] >= floor) ? true : false;
                                    ^
required: boolean[]
found:    boolean`

I am wondering about a way to change the boolean to a boolean array or if a different solution is needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How much do you know about arrays?

Comment: I think you mean:

    results[i] = (someNumbers[i] >= floor);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like what you want is

```
boolean[] results = new boolean[someNumbers.length]; 
    // you have to initialize it
for (int i = 0; i < someNumbers.length; i++) {
    results[i] = someNumbers[i] >= floor; // ? true : false is redundant
    // ^ you're setting the ith element of the array, not the whole array
}

return results;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to store boolean values in each cell of an array. Change results to results[i]

```
 public boolean[] boolsRule(int floor, int[] someNumbers) {

        boolean[] results;
        for (int i = 0; i < someNumbers.length; i++) {
            results[i] = (someNumbers[i] >= floor) ? true : false;
        }

        return results;
    }
```